# Memset на ассемблере

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, с реализацией вызова memset в ассемблере. Я пишу ассемблерную вставку в программу на Си, нужно заполнить нулями булевский массив bl, он объявлен в main. При компиляции ругается на строчку `call   memset` выдает ошибки "error C2420: memset: недопустимый символ в первый операнд" и "error C2415: недопустимый тип операнда"    Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибки.

```
bool bl[100000]
int main()
{
_asm
{
push    100000
push    0
push   bl
call    memset
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BL`, он же `bl` - это регистр процессора такой. Причём вам ещё повезло что 8-битный, поэтому ошибка уже на стадии компиляции проявляется (команда `push` с 8-битными операндами не работает). Назвали бы переменную `bx` или `ebx`, или ещё как-то из этой области - всё бы молча скомпилировалось, а грохнулось бы уже во время работы.

P.S. Кстати, вы в курсе, что если ваш `bool` не однобайтовый, то вы обнуляете только часть массива?

**UPD** Вот такой код после всяких экспериментов и исправлений в студии 2010 собирался и заработал без проблем:

```
/*
    main.c
*/
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char bbb[16] = { 0 };
    _asm
    {
        push 15
        push 48
        lea eax, bbb
        push eax
        call memset
        add esp, 12
    }
    printf( "%s\n", bbb );
    return 0;
}
```

[Пруфлинк!](http://ato.su/resizer/i/d/1/6d5d8b3.jpg)

**UPD2** Ура @Uchenitsa !

Ещё одна особенность студии: если студия настроена на использование "встроенных" функций (например `/Oi` или как-то ещё), то некоторых "умолчательных" функций она может не увидеть в таких вставках.

[Подробности](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/sctyh01s(v=vs.120).aspx), [список таких функций](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/tzkfha43.aspx) (`memset()` там как раз есть).

Решение:

```
#pragma function(memset)
```

Comment: я изменила bl на _bl, но компилятор все равно выдает все те же ошибки.

Comment: Не знаю какой у вас компилятор, но всё-таки попробуйте почитать хоть минимальную справку про использование встроенного ассемблера в нём. Вдруг окажется, что переменные типа `_bl` являются в нём псевдонимами для имён регистров? Как и во  многих dos/windows компиляторах, если помню.

Comment: Компилятор Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: Так и что его руководство говорит насчёт подобных имён переменных? Я имею в виду совпадающих с названиями регистров, но начинающихся с подчёркивания.

Comment: В руководство не смотрела, поменяла название массива на block. Увы, ничего не изменилось(  последняя версия этого кусочка программы выглядит так:    `push 100000` `push 0` `push offset block` `call memset`

Comment: Ну, тут уже только вслепую по памяти могу - windows в руках давно не держал :) Может MASM не понимает `push offset`, можно попробовать: `mov eax, offset ... // push eax`

Comment: спасибо, что помогаете) попробовала, как вы сказали, не работает, ошибки одни и те же

Comment: А сейчас точно на строку с BL ошибка-то? Может он теперь не может решить какая разрядность у ноля: 32 или 64 бита :)

Comment: Когда я кликаю на текст ошибки, он указывает строку call memset

Comment: Расчехлил студию 2010. Там с `bl`  таки да, не работает :) Но и дальше тоже, даже если переименовать переменную в `bbb`. Помогло: не `offset bbb`, а так: `lea eax, bbb / push eax`. Проверьте, pls, на 2013.

Comment: А не может ли быть причина в том, что ассемблер не видит имени memset? Хидеров нет или name mangling какой?

Comment: @klopp, даже говорить боюсь, опять ошибки

Comment: Какие именно ошибки? И да - memset() в каких-нибудь заголовках определяется?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, mangling точно не при чём. memset - по определению extern C, поэтому что в плюсах, что в чистом C... См. обновление ответа.

Comment: Простите, не смог удержаться и не запостить вот [эту](http://s.pikabu.ru/post_img/2013/08/13/1/1376344525_864322181.jpg) картинку

Comment: @kloppСпасибо за ваши комментарии, в проблеме разобралась. Стоило в сишной части программы написать #pragma function(memset) и все заработало!

Comment: Вот оно что, Михалыч! Действительно, если студия настроена на использование "встроенных" функций (например `/Oi` или как-то ещё), то так может и не видеть. Подробности: [раз](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/sctyh01s(v=vs.120).aspx), [два](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/tzkfha43.aspx). В общем, всё у них не как у людей :)